# What is the counterpart of the pseudocode annotation in UML class diagram

Tags: design-patterns, uml, class-diagram

In the GOF23 book [Design Patterns Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software], there is *pseudocode annotation* in the *class diagrams*. It is a very helpful tool.

[image: <img src="http://www.cs.unc.edu/~stotts/GOF/hires/Pictures/class088.gif" alt="annotation" />]

But I can not find the counterpart in UML class diagrams, so would like to know **if there is the counterpart of *pseudocode annotation* in UML class diagrams**

Comment: I'm not really clear what you're asking. Your example is exactly a case of pseudocode used in UML class diagram. Of course arrows are poorly shaped here (heads should be open in most cases and for generalization head should be at the arrow end, not in the middle), but except that your example is your answer to the question.

Comment: That is actually not UML but an OMT class diagram, a predecessor of UML. I once also thought is was UML

Comment: Blimey, it is @Rui, that take's me back.

Comment: @muszeo it is what? :) OMT class diagram? but strictly speaking it is not UML

Comment: Yes OMT, I remember those...

Comment: Oh well, I didn't realize it is OMT. One can see the origins I guess ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One can claim that the above is illegal UML (since the note connector is wrong). However, you can just attach the note to the class and augment the note (to show the operation which is meant).

Enterprise Architect shows behavior like this:

[image]

(the `blabla` is the behavior).

Note: I have to check with the UML specs whether this is legal UML. Though EA is quite compliant, it has a few flaws too.

**Edit**: I have checked the UML 2.5 specs. Pseudo code is not really mentioned and there's no place where they tell how to show it. Only with Actions/States they talk about showing behavior. E.g. on p. 329:

> the optional `<behavior-expression>` is an expression specifying the effect Behavior written in some vendor-specific or standard textual surface language (see sub clause 16.1)

So it's up to you to "invent" your notation, document it in your domain, and use it appropriately.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It makes senses (Y) But I  still prefer to waiting for more answers or opinions :)

Comment: Well, behavior-expression can be in any language, formal or informal. Pseudocode is fully valid there. I don't think you'll get any better answer than this one ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A note is shown in a UML class diagram nearly exactly like your *pseudocode annotation*:

[image]

In this case, it explains how the `toString()` method is implemented.